# All pods being terminated on cluster node when GKE runs update script

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a staging cluster with a single node on GKE:

```
    Master version: 1.6.4
    Node version: 1.6.4
    Node image: container-vm
    Automatic upgrades: Disabled
    Automatic repair: Disabled
```

It looks like GCP is running some kind of automated script that runs kube-up: Logs start with:

```
    Running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
    == kube-up node config starting ==
    ...
```

Some salt stuff runs, then I see a number of log errors and warns:

```
    W  Your kernel does not support swap memory limit. 
    W  Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit. 
    W  Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs period 
    W  Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas 
    W  mountpoint for pids not found 
    E  Failed to load container 02e6b71a1cb88b3f07cd160a03417264cd8a9a6265821c467ef446ed52e74662: open /var/lib/docker/containers/02e6b71a1cb88b3f07cd160a03417264cd8a9a6265821c467ef446ed52e74662/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 0dbc16ff7b8d3f5defb42f5297215439676bf4c4c4c1d66383af7ab11a3d1a59: open /var/lib/docker/containers/0dbc16ff7b8d3f5defb42f5297215439676bf4c4c4c1d66383af7ab11a3d1a59/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 136ca2a59327c70a7fb917976ff91520eb8209e8dc68a455abac315c47a5aa6e: open /var/lib/docker/containers/136ca2a59327c70a7fb917976ff91520eb8209e8dc68a455abac315c47a5aa6e/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 1392705d8d32f7353d9854570f7d8e7191c80c23f6439047eb4f69697fbe6e61: open /var/lib/docker/containers/1392705d8d32f7353d9854570f7d8e7191c80c23f6439047eb4f69697fbe6e61/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 1fafdae38df78c3d2b408850398d833569b5787804ad9c6f6c455f2af2fc7350: open /var/lib/docker/containers/1fafdae38df78c3d2b408850398d833569b5787804ad9c6f6c455f2af2fc7350/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 2f531c52bc4db2377e4b330d76cdc32ed194bfb11109474175b4a331de650579: open /var/lib/docker/containers/2f531c52bc4db2377e4b330d76cdc32ed194bfb11109474175b4a331de650579/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 3bbb45b41cfdc50906e51b3384b90718c00a9323ecee4a590d309c5f5cb93f26: open /var/lib/docker/containers/3bbb45b41cfdc50906e51b3384b90718c00a9323ecee4a590d309c5f5cb93f26/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 46b699856050191dce22eac4dc01d8499881af7c2ba63a43e8cd0a1f8e864551: open /var/lib/docker/containers/46b699856050191dce22eac4dc01d8499881af7c2ba63a43e8cd0a1f8e864551/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 5aad8b929edac55e3ce0fb8ccd0718688ac9ca472a8cb632830790561e2c5a3d: open /var/lib/docker/containers/5aad8b929edac55e3ce0fb8ccd0718688ac9ca472a8cb632830790561e2c5a3d/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 646b86bd0834f620fd48b37531789c4c4e8207e12609b355d8809d2dc5346c03: open /var/lib/docker/containers/646b86bd0834f620fd48b37531789c4c4e8207e12609b355d8809d2dc5346c03/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 88a77d68067ed43c7e1a6a84ba26f4683bc66f6fecce335e987d1d357b47866b: open /var/lib/docker/containers/88a77d68067ed43c7e1a6a84ba26f4683bc66f6fecce335e987d1d357b47866b/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 89b5a00b7472a623a1302c2dc9121d237d6d45d01a983707a2d72f18089c362a: open /var/lib/docker/containers/89b5a00b7472a623a1302c2dc9121d237d6d45d01a983707a2d72f18089c362a/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 8bf1fdece8803a0b0d5d56b7a10d8e5b1d9705837a76594e435df7369b2b0652: open /var/lib/docker/containers/8bf1fdece8803a0b0d5d56b7a10d8e5b1d9705837a76594e435df7369b2b0652/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 970fcc46e3c7947658f9166d48feb4703b2aecf5c5460f2820aa4d3a51c9a86d: open /var/lib/docker/containers/970fcc46e3c7947658f9166d48feb4703b2aecf5c5460f2820aa4d3a51c9a86d/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container 9caa5d5cf132f87e0c92b537194a5d38e912d70df575534d4059d72e46ee7945: open /var/lib/docker/containers/9caa5d5cf132f87e0c92b537194a5d38e912d70df575534d4059d72e46ee7945/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container acb52eec4ac0734fcd1df16a81f5761b466862a9ff142c400ddb580080351c70: open /var/lib/docker/containers/acb52eec4ac0734fcd1df16a81f5761b466862a9ff142c400ddb580080351c70/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container acbf9f7a3f48107a5e04fcfaf7eca91af68c59b3a2122b02e8216bc6c20558d6: open /var/lib/docker/containers/acbf9f7a3f48107a5e04fcfaf7eca91af68c59b3a2122b02e8216bc6c20558d6/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container b5f331599ff45b1b23402b3c42d46428516780ee5f558a064af4af18d3afe85c: open /var/lib/docker/containers/b5f331599ff45b1b23402b3c42d46428516780ee5f558a064af4af18d3afe85c/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container b8910a3b49ec0d20caa239fe12935e2b8822245b64bdca7a1586cbbee48c6c3f: open /var/lib/docker/containers/b8910a3b49ec0d20caa239fe12935e2b8822245b64bdca7a1586cbbee48c6c3f/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container d2daa4363c5a5e466170f7da17006f282959987ab2fe4c6505a363415790a775: open /var/lib/docker/containers/d2daa4363c5a5e466170f7da17006f282959987ab2fe4c6505a363415790a775/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container f0ec736eb20a001baa89c28b3d4b575364343cc8a20d0235eee1ec4ea71f9f3c: open /var/lib/docker/containers/f0ec736eb20a001baa89c28b3d4b575364343cc8a20d0235eee1ec4ea71f9f3c/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    E  Failed to load container fa347d27a38ef8375e9dfda680aab15e8a00b8e5df25b37363f0419a89235f0a: open /var/lib/docker/containers/fa347d27a38ef8375e9dfda680aab15e8a00b8e5df25b37363f0419a89235f0a/config.v2.json: no such file or directory 
    W  error locating sandbox id cdb76f2858e25972f72f957a37adb0a3df2d558dc88f997a2e5ffadf0b440a0c: sandbox cdb76f2858e25972f72f957a37adb0a3df2d558dc88f997a2e5ffadf0b440a0c not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/a5822a61de2a4d1e57f5b1c3cf0b916cd152454a57f8dc3ce4cea37de7d2a22d/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id b3da48f8e5731c788ecf4147a6ae2e971126615966b7153bce3e0b120addc8b9: sandbox b3da48f8e5731c788ecf4147a6ae2e971126615966b7153bce3e0b120addc8b9 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/5ca0504afa404e1b1fd67c4599143b3ece4c59ab1005e40f5ec055bf25824e22/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id b78e948eb6e4e852319e5e781163f1804639208f7e9ba5da93f3c791ef51dc54: sandbox b78e948eb6e4e852319e5e781163f1804639208f7e9ba5da93f3c791ef51dc54 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/62b9e4d59a43d80368ca031c079df44fab92e3fcab5a6f7fca97d18cf9ffc125/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id b0a1743bee8476b6b749367b65962d93caeef5136a27fa246a6051d275e30298: sandbox b0a1743bee8476b6b749367b65962d93caeef5136a27fa246a6051d275e30298 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/9bd31076040e4a1232d5591652a5ac41c23b187d62f6395e88f25c399b8ec82c/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 2c46e9bad063ad3625e9bec536eaa6f0c2d03172e97bd65b28d8d57f63a113a6: sandbox 2c46e9bad063ad3625e9bec536eaa6f0c2d03172e97bd65b28d8d57f63a113a6 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/850e742b1a81fb2e6fafc1a458ead94ce992dc6095cb987a70fa8da667f8762a/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 5b6ab879bf35917005b27184b19aae4dd31340ca80163a18288aa6257b4309ea: sandbox 5b6ab879bf35917005b27184b19aae4dd31340ca80163a18288aa6257b4309ea not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/2eb2058e22339e252bfbea0c85906675385957db4a5c31254f43c466dd2e5167/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 1272109f4709b65670c8f171210eaebec01636c5466670bfb1f17ad82ccbb3e1: sandbox 1272109f4709b65670c8f171210eaebec01636c5466670bfb1f17ad82ccbb3e1 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/b1c41fa3d983a03bb834f719f852a62ec3197d1976c2ef6ae21798ab31c44a2c/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 1ddbac33ac40c037852865dada495ae63389d060b5fd2092a832ea0a38104b3d: sandbox 1ddbac33ac40c037852865dada495ae63389d060b5fd2092a832ea0a38104b3d not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/b09f56bba891fe6ec86d5453c6b357256578179a000b883f2672f15608295e4e/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 5a0ee6a09c9148d2998de38701fd1aa79cde9a5e344c14d1af51ca7b8c0c278e: sandbox 5a0ee6a09c9148d2998de38701fd1aa79cde9a5e344c14d1af51ca7b8c0c278e not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/8cd0c1f792e58616041e57270266920324417b486059303a291179d355b6b36e/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 421e1ed3c6c68ac12d8dd4b1795c6af01fe16d939b6fc1acd1a48e82004b9ad6: sandbox 421e1ed3c6c68ac12d8dd4b1795c6af01fe16d939b6fc1acd1a48e82004b9ad6 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/23e7b7c49794db30ed3d349aba50303b7e11189f4d35ef17c77bcfda7362bf54/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id d7be73201ebf4ed12094dd2b1b5e8e56feb6b2b77cccff118c1defea7c0a4ec8: sandbox d7be73201ebf4ed12094dd2b1b5e8e56feb6b2b77cccff118c1defea7c0a4ec8 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/c21bf9eeb8bd3336595de09f6ad68472a72aa46fd3970833a5e89c37fde2f108/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 01a0d1d3040bf02e3a127e10887f0bf2ac6dd62299c2a92dbd93450eaec515bb: sandbox 01a0d1d3040bf02e3a127e10887f0bf2ac6dd62299c2a92dbd93450eaec515bb not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/545ebfaa8ae8a679bbcd2af35b48db54c5331292e9af0f3d2d1d586c199f4835/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 6c4c41e4dc3df6ca397648cc557acae615e5e522e91dea789100e78c2af1d0fd: sandbox 6c4c41e4dc3df6ca397648cc557acae615e5e522e91dea789100e78c2af1d0fd not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/33f6d9936339fd3e7e0ba5fa9480eb4c9f6eacc488d2f36d0c585cce5732f54f/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 5cb12758023f2ace765b82c8028c68aae8e3ed8721cdc1a07ef9102587973746: sandbox 5cb12758023f2ace765b82c8028c68aae8e3ed8721cdc1a07ef9102587973746 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/90715dd2f6da7d25ad5008720296a838d0ea950d086cb27f80927887c2f14f67/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 135bd6b407a14e28d8c157b068100f777e0aa028a07863404e63269cf10e3196: sandbox 135bd6b407a14e28d8c157b068100f777e0aa028a07863404e63269cf10e3196 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/b1a74e3dbb94cf180beeb99f74f19755b9615fb0835f1c307f97f024737a543d/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id d621c699e6ac4feb71a69cca0afe4b7175ab212110a3dd8c4618762351ec4b3f: sandbox d621c699e6ac4feb71a69cca0afe4b7175ab212110a3dd8c4618762351ec4b3f not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/0c3cf82e1dc6bf73d84e613e2708af4f5b0c64c39336b2570916d52a06a88251/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 986222a375fbcba530e84d23210ee4702f71744cdd8b4adedbab9a2f80c8fbd9: sandbox 986222a375fbcba530e84d23210ee4702f71744cdd8b4adedbab9a2f80c8fbd9 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/e2799ef225e31260a105e3dd92b2715d32688658ec763b3c138c0621734d7479/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 32f061961b38dca041ce37ad94d29ec8a116d53f0530b2543e806d74236c6340: sandbox 32f061961b38dca041ce37ad94d29ec8a116d53f0530b2543e806d74236c6340 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/8e69a8754fdfb435399880036912ae16a0674e9b7186815e8a1a116e2c9e330b/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id b1771bb186b19c630fc8782bc3875bd65395609b22f5ca71c095b8a1909d16ae: sandbox b1771bb186b19c630fc8782bc3875bd65395609b22f5ca71c095b8a1909d16ae not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/96f6e2d1cd40d77f5cf9c89f414e6f6ef9a56b5e9780173e58f5a6dae3719f44/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 56e3fbd6b7a60bc9213eaa554e727f50b03dfc52cd0891b580e7347fb450d14b: sandbox 56e3fbd6b7a60bc9213eaa554e727f50b03dfc52cd0891b580e7347fb450d14b not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/8343cb9e43ddad4cccc51706f41e4f78d2c423edbd5e2a03094e5380802d586d/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 4593a0aa717a9f9fe341a77c8b8d59b45d13fad40fedb4888ea5983c1be8eaad: sandbox 4593a0aa717a9f9fe341a77c8b8d59b45d13fad40fedb4888ea5983c1be8eaad not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/173db6519963e119816e942dabffb1318dc286e585aa3f4c8d24273242f04c55/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 5150061cf0e59600bdf038688c6646be3a982ab3f0f9eecacfca084aa474ae46: sandbox 5150061cf0e59600bdf038688c6646be3a982ab3f0f9eecacfca084aa474ae46 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/035fd606167a7b04098739bb7b9cb479e47c40c0615e2a24feb96a881d9f201e/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 6dffc02c3aa6fd5232d678c420b0201d7da74ec71eb3d8149bf054b80dfd4b01: sandbox 6dffc02c3aa6fd5232d678c420b0201d7da74ec71eb3d8149bf054b80dfd4b01 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/41f58fc76cdeb91330b32fecaff84a5cc40d69b9151b8c27b6cf2cc9f9cb8877/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 0c7c9d68bca5d8eb3351c127347c52247b3d98a74a62f718db45b6da06a7ee9c: sandbox 0c7c9d68bca5d8eb3351c127347c52247b3d98a74a62f718db45b6da06a7ee9c not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/d316e1f1d40da238e1aa5e4800f7306228359ce8ff4b42135749667a485d6d4f/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 07f73d1c012ada224682a9aca924dcd357cfd2afa0b2e17ae8792b9a872d3d91: sandbox 07f73d1c012ada224682a9aca924dcd357cfd2afa0b2e17ae8792b9a872d3d91 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/de47a6a8b66a7c05b341f15d69967277be87ca19d27a7f24cdcd135dead2650b/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id fda885878ba25b4229b9b8ba6804760205ffb738ade84070b57e3289a52d7ea4: sandbox fda885878ba25b4229b9b8ba6804760205ffb738ade84070b57e3289a52d7ea4 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/abda65f65db7817df28a2f2daf95f35c88957a455315d21ada3d2a34654e1d7d/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 6bb1ec3cc013d6df864bb66eb8dc995ded78ac9e8e6f409c68bdf3c454870535: sandbox 6bb1ec3cc013d6df864bb66eb8dc995ded78ac9e8e6f409c68bdf3c454870535 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/1eac5a343c664373656acbad074f006cd7f2b912cc6cc748137d3d54436e450d/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 988c97066b0c28a93d3205beb4d6eca65d86abd250bdb9f81b08015827856f7e: sandbox 988c97066b0c28a93d3205beb4d6eca65d86abd250bdb9f81b08015827856f7e not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/bcea85a5440f7c46c1f33c46690a0047a861f29e56523c20eb029247c45ad301/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 25607ac39946e4d41f52d9a33eaac9335ee0ae07a01d7b161862b6ee7d7846e8: sandbox 25607ac39946e4d41f52d9a33eaac9335ee0ae07a01d7b161862b6ee7d7846e8 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/3ec62a642f3f8c4c591a99a6993e880cbf3d75f5ccb53a468c3bd42506f4bb1e/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id eee52a9422642858a1965c36ed4a869d8ec8c8118a7a9313310ce207f257dfb5: sandbox eee52a9422642858a1965c36ed4a869d8ec8c8118a7a9313310ce207f257dfb5 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/c9426b66c89e064fb180a528e4235552fccad5f386ce2207aa8443083039a82f/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 99deb6072346f8d7daa8d107fa9d358d6ebb76fe2c2ffd3feeae1f7668e9521e: sandbox 99deb6072346f8d7daa8d107fa9d358d6ebb76fe2c2ffd3feeae1f7668e9521e not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/0eb9bc7e9d4e74587202daa35ad00b3522dfb45153640b2b51ce01d676b09d66/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 617433203c828df35287d466907f50b67d0e8b585687ec014f24ba06b1480e68: sandbox 617433203c828df35287d466907f50b67d0e8b585687ec014f24ba06b1480e68 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/548e1dee5845eb177a85ff0b3967673d48c1d84bf4825a606af4a6f1f64d7b50/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 1fb53087e317441d8857596f549582ee02124b45eae3db3f6a67cc1d8fbcf6eb: sandbox 1fb53087e317441d8857596f549582ee02124b45eae3db3f6a67cc1d8fbcf6eb not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/5e397937c16eab55490daee50f182c4c11b5f4f586d89f642ee274915d96ab6c/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 14fd0327bffc94b8f9ab5f6a6cd830ee831cf54e02b3707654edb64f357d7f00: sandbox 14fd0327bffc94b8f9ab5f6a6cd830ee831cf54e02b3707654edb64f357d7f00 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/118d022f59656a323c8a844a12aa217a9026ab7ad98dd93f360b87fa0e240117/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 3bf74d488aa0b81300a9ad2c28617f95066bd660e2583d8a75b505a812090216: sandbox 3bf74d488aa0b81300a9ad2c28617f95066bd660e2583d8a75b505a812090216 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/14157daa3896036df01591619d92222a2c27dc52b7db5e5b70511e61f7be0d67/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 742d584bc3e86e0d398749fdf7ff29e58c5b326dc061f382b0086cd7faa80d2c: sandbox 742d584bc3e86e0d398749fdf7ff29e58c5b326dc061f382b0086cd7faa80d2c not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/54b0b8761d267e662c60d93f44b47b4a9a5d6346d33c9820d2172ac3a7e6af0e/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 189e6bead98f04773cc3fa0cc38db9c5870be457602c5582ebde612af1ab819d: sandbox 189e6bead98f04773cc3fa0cc38db9c5870be457602c5582ebde612af1ab819d not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/fde334c90d81db1a87d206e8929a90101f4803233c22901d1603dadf0c10395d/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id 34495706772a2c8c0bd11841bcbdf8b0a79c6f939dbf87655606b2d052111bdb: sandbox 34495706772a2c8c0bd11841bcbdf8b0a79c6f939dbf87655606b2d052111bdb not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/575f079450e13f347339a4eedd240f25132754c8dd4f086ea8858db18e302a2d/shm: invalid argument 
    W  error locating sandbox id fce54053982f760573327f6fea40f4699cac4372a680364f50cfc6c28c760222: sandbox fce54053982f760573327f6fea40f4699cac4372a680364f50cfc6c28c760222 not found 
    W  failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/a2e732964390aa607dcbc7e1f0631df1336096d8d9534fc5eb05148b740b0870/shm: invalid argument 
    W  Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
```

I can't see what's happening on the master but I assume a complementary script is running there because `kubectl describe pods` and `kubectl -n kube-system describe pods` all return that the node pods and the system pods were terminated at the same time:

```
    Last State:     Terminated
        Reason:     Completed
        Exit Code:  0
        Started:        Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 +0000
        Finished:       Mon, 19 Jun 2017 03:22:01 -0500
```

Has anyone else encountered this? I'm not seeing it on older clusters running < v1.6.